# Nepenthes pitcher cups rotting and turning black

Tags: carnivorous-plants, rot, nepenthes

I just feed one of the pitchers half a mealworm and in 2 days it looks like this. And it smells really bad. I don't understand what I did wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The stuff in the pitcher, and the pitcher itself, are rotting.

Given the color I'd say you gave it too much food. Stick with smaller flying insects, or better yet, a dilute fertilizer like Maxsea or Jack's, especially if it's going to be indoors. I use 1/4 tsp of Jack's All Purpose 20-20-20 to a gallon of distilled water, and fill the pitchers ~1/2 full (do NOT fertilize the medium). Fertilizer in the pitchers will give the plant the nutrients it requires and save you from the stink of rotting dead stuff.